# Rfacebook package

Tags: r, facebook

I'm getting great result with the new Rfacebook package, but I can't scrape results from closed groups even if I'm a member of the group. I get

No public posts were found

Scraping open groups works fine. Is this a bug or a feature. How can a transfer my membership in a group to my permissions as a developer?

Comment: That is by design; Facebook has limited access to groups with API version 2.4. The conditions under which you can read a group’s feed are mentioned in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group/feed#read

Comment: So how might I get user_managed_groups permissions to scrape?

Comment: How do you get _any_ permission …? By asking the user for it, via the login dialog, of course.

Comment: Sorry for a rookie question . . . ask through the JavaScript SDK? I've just been pasting tokens into my R code, for I fear I'm getting in over my head!

Comment: The JS SDK’s FB.login is one way of triggering login, yes. (There are others as well, see docs.) But for testing purposes, you can also generate access tokens in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) – just select your app from the dropdown, click Get Token->Get User Access token, and then select the permissions you want.

Comment: Looking at the Rfacebook documentation, it specifies "Extract list of posts from a public Facebook group," so I wonder if I'll get anywhere even with the right permissions and token. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Again: The FB API documentation clearly specifies under which conditions you can get access to a group’s feed – see link in first comment.

Comment: I've generated a temporary token with user_managed_groups permissions but still get the same error. I wonder if this a limitation of Rfacebook issue

Comment: Try and make a post using that token in Graph API Explorer, then you’ll know.

Comment: (Just to be clear, we’re talking about posting into a group that actually are an admin of, right?)

Comment: No, not posting, just scraping posts for a closed group. What are those permissions?

Comment: Again: [`GOTO 10.`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925511/rfacebook-package?noredirect=1#comment61412526_36925511)